# need help on the use of promise with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, promise, html2canvas

Essentially, I need to extract the dataURL from the canvas and return it.

```
function getImage() {
  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
      var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      resolve(image);
    });
  });

  p.then(function (image) {
      return image;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Please help to correct my code.

Comment: a) [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) b) don't try to synchronously `return` a value when you cannot. There's just no way to do that. Return the promise for the URL instead, and adapt your caller.

Comment: Your code can reduced to `function getImage() {
  return html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
   image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   return image;
  }).catch(function (err) { console.log(err) });
 }` Your function is now a promise, use it like this `getImage().then(function(image) {  })`.

Comment: thanks @ShanShan for your help